# Unable to remove input box border

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the border of a input box but I'm not sure why it isn't working when I render it. I'm using React.JS to render the page, but I don't think that is the problem.

React.JS

```
    return (
        <div>
            <form className = "formPosition">
                <div className = "formTitle">Hello.</div>
                <div className = "formDescription">Please enter your username and password</div>
                <div className = "usernameFormat">
                    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Username"/><br/>
                </div>
                <div className = "passwordFormat">
                    <input type = "password" placeholder = "Password"/><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

CSS for the inputbox

```
input [type=text], input [type=password]
{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="page-body">

      </div>

  </body>

  <script src="javascripts/bundle.js"></script>

</html>
```

I would image adding `color:red` into the input CSS would change the color of the text, but it didn't. I feel like I am over looking something really obvious.

Comment: Where are you testing this? Try also `outline: none`

Comment: I am testing this on my local machine using a server set up with node.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CSS, spaces are importants and can change everything.

You have:

```
input [type=text], input [type=password]
{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

And it should be:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password]
{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

The first code targets a `<input>` that have a children with the attribute `type="text"`, or the same as this:

```
 <input>
   <othertag type="text">
 </input>
```

The second, targets a `<input>` with the attribute `type="text"` itself:

```
 <input type="text">
```

### EDIT

I create a snippet to show the issue to other people than don't understand what happens.

This is the first code:

```css
input [type=text], input [type=password]
{
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

This is the second code:

```css
input[type=text], input[type=password]
{
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you Marcos; I had a feeling it was something really obvious.

Comment: You are welcome. Take care of the spaces in the same selector. Each space targets a children. It's called descendant.

Comment: Check as correct answer when you can. Good luck and see you soon :)